# Firebase query with queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToLast(10) does not return one of the last 10 items

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load the last 10 products that have been added to the all_products table in firebase.

I run the following query with version 3.2.0 of the firebase SDK:

```
 let fbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("products_all").queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToLast(10).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let keyString = (item as! FIRDataSnapshot).key
```

However, the items that get returned are not the last 10 items in this table. I have about 1017 products in this table and the first item that gets returned in this query is item 973, while it should be item 1008.

My firebase looks like this (I used childByAutoId to add the products):

```
{
  "products_all" : {
    "-KFOiZDrbR4eq4fXSdMZ" : {
      "affiliate_url" : "https://some.link.com",
      "description" : "product description",
      "image_url" : "https://image.url.com/firstImage.jpg",
      "images" : [ "https://image.url.com/firstImage.jpg", "https://image.url.com/secondImage.jpg" ],
      "merchant" : "merchant.com",
      "price_usd" : "100.00",
      "title" : "product title"
    },
    ...,
    "-KFtOmT_Hq-48chbHh7I" : {
      "affiliate_url" : "https://another.link.com",
      "description" : "another product description",
      "image_url" : "https://image.link.com/anotherImage.jpg",
      "images" : [ "https://image.link.com/anotherImage.jpg" ],
      "merchant" : "anothermerchant.com",
      "original_currency" : "GBP",
      "original_price" : "255",
      "price_usd" : "364.65",
      "product_category" : "Bracelet",
      "external_product_id" : "Anothermerchant-123",
      "title" : "another product title"
    },
    ...,
    "-KFtOmTlcb5-PTQ6kTv8" : {
      "affiliate_url" : "https://last.product.com",
      "description" : "last product description",
      "image_url" : "https://last.product.com/image.jpg",
      "images" : [ "https://last.product.com/image.jpg" ],
      "merchant" : "anothermerchant.com",
      "original_currency" : "GBP",
      "original_price" : "179",
      "price_usd" : "268.5",
      "product_category" : "Bracelet",
      "scraped_product_id" : "anothermerchant-493",
      "title" : "last product title"
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also, the last element in the batch of 10 is number 992 - so the 10 items are neither in the last 10, nor are their all 'neighbours'.

First keys that were included:
 -KFtOmT_Hq-48chbHh7I
 -KFtOmT_Hq-48chbHh7J
 -KFtOmT_Hq-48chbHh7K

Subsequent keys that were skipped:
 -KFtOmT0Qj3mrCTlxOfj
 -KFtOmT1jouJgm8x_Mi7
 -KFtOmT4GUpXtd9Y90sq
 -KFtOmT4GUpXtd9Y90sr
 -KFtOmT57vidxDl_jpj_
 -KFtOmT57vidxDl_jpja
 -KFtOmT9yuy-1G8WBrsE

Then some keys were included and others again excluded, the 'coverage' is patchy.

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb here on Stackoverflow to include your Firebase structure as text and also a complete structure snippet. Can you go to your Firebase Dashboard and export your structure and replace the image with that text?

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I have included the Firebase structure but simplified the full content slightly - I hope that's ok?

Comment: It's great! Can you double check the query - it may be malformed. I think the .database parameter is extraneous as that returns a Firebase instance, not a reference, so it should be removed.

Comment: That's how it works with the latest version of the Firebase SDK after their upgrade, v3.2.0 @Jay - see the new docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start#set_up_firebase_database

Comment: I did try changing the query to a .ChildValue type query. I get different products out of the database now, but still not the exact last 10, there are still 'holes' in the results (products that do not get returned by firebase) and it doesn't start/end with the last product.

Comment: This is certainly perplexing. There must be something else influencing the returned data. Can you possibly post more code? Also, can you change your query to return the last 3 items (instead of 10) and then post the actual last three items from your database as text?

Comment: Somewhat similar query answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39437711/6297658