# Retrieve only 5 users at a time :Firebase [like Instagram]

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, updates

For the past few days, I have been trying to create an Instagram-like feed for my app. To be more specific: load new posts (5) each time the user updates the feed from the bottom.

I am currently using Firebase to both store and display my data.

My code so far, looks like this:

```
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

    var dict = [String:Any]()
    var posts = [[String:Any]]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        loadValues()

    }

    func loadValues() {

        dict.removeAll()
        posts.removeAll()


        ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByChild("timeCreated").queryLimitedToLast(5).observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let timeCreated = snapshot.value!["timeCreated"] as? Int {
                self.dict["timeCreated"] = timeCreated
            }

            if let postText = snapshot.value!["postText"] as? String {
                self.dict["postText"] = postText
            }


            self.posts.append(self.dict)


            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }




    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height {

            //tableView.tableFooterView!.hidden = true
            let pagingSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
            pagingSpinner.startAnimating()
            pagingSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
            pagingSpinner.sizeToFit()
            tableView.tableFooterView = pagingSpinner

            //loadMore(5)

        } else {

            let pagingSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
            pagingSpinner.stopAnimating()
            pagingSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
            pagingSpinner.sizeToFit()
            pagingSpinner.hidden = true
            tableView.tableFooterView = pagingSpinner
            tableView.tableFooterView?.hidden = true


        }


    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return posts.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if let postText = posts[indexPath.row]["postText"] as? String {
            cell.textLabel!.text = postText
        }

        return cell

    }

    func loadMore(increment:Int) {

        //What should go in here?

    }
```

So what I am trying to do here - is that I am detecting when the user has scrolled to the bottom (in my scrollViewDidScroll function. Then I am sinply displaying the activity indicator, and calling the function loadMore(5) where 5 is the amount of new posts that I want to display.

So here I have two problems. The timeCreated variable is simply a timestamp, where I have ten records (1-10, where 10 is the newest, and 1 is the oldest). With this code that I have now, the tableView displays the data in an ascending view, starting at 5 and ending at 10.

I have tried to reverse the array of dictionaries (post) by simply doing a .reverse() before appending the dict in the loadValues function. as I simply want it to display 10 at the top, and 5 at the bottom.

The second problem I have is that I can't really seem to find a good and effective way of updating the tableView (adding another 5 records). I have tried to simply just have a global variable with the default value of 5, and then on loadMore simply plus it by five, and then do a removeAll() on both the dict and posts - with no luck (the tableView scrolls to the top, which I don't want to). I have also tried to play with both queryLimitedTolast and queryLimitedToFirst where I ended up duplicating some data.

So in other words, I also need to check that the user can in fact load 5 new unique posts (or ex. 3, if there's only 3 unique posts left).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would approach this?

Help would be greatly appreciated, as I have struggled with this for the past two days now.

Comment: PS: I am happy to share my Firebase data structure, if this is necessary.

Comment: I think i solved it. Look at the discussion, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123147/discussion-between-dravidian-and-askaale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `tableView` update your **DataSource** instead of adding a row at a particular index. using `struct` is a common aproach.

```
struct dataS {

var postData : String!
var index_Initial : Int!

init(post : String!, ind : Int!)
{
 self.postData = post
 self.index_Initial = ind
  }

}
```

- Declare an array of type **`dataSourceS`**

  ```
       var dataFeed= [dataS]()
  ```
- For knowing that how many posts you have already retrived , you need to keep the index of each post in the the `post` node itself.Which can be done by counting the no of children in the `post` node and incrementing it by one.Or creating a complete separate node of

  ```
  noOfPosts: 100, //Lets say there are 100 posts in your DB 

   Posts : {
    Post1:{


       text : asdasdasd,
       index : 12               

        },

     Post2:{


       text : asdasddasdasd,
       index : 13              

        },.....
   }
  ```

Your final code will look something like this:-

```
 import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var dataFeed = [dataS]()
let pagingSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
var totalNoOfPost : Int!



@IBOutlet weak var customTableView: UITableView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    customTableView.delegate = self
    customTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in

        if let postDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

             self.totalNoOfPost = postDict.count

                self.loadMore()
        }
    })

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataFeed.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = customTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as! customTableViewCell
    if dataFeed.count > 0{
    cell.poatLabel.text = dataFeed[indexPath.row].postData
    }
    return cell
}

func loadMore(){

    let initialFeedCount : Int = dataFeed.count

    if totalNoOfPost - initialFeedCount - 4 > 0{

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("index").queryStartingAtValue(totalNoOfPost - initialFeedCount - 4).queryEndingAtValue(totalNoOfPost - initialFeedCount).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(recievedSnap) in

        if recievedSnap.exists(){

        for each in recievedSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]{
            let temp = dataS.init(post: each.1["text"] as! String, ind : each.1["index"] as! Int)
            self.dataFeed.insert(temp, atIndex: 5 * Int(self.dataFeed.count/5))
            self.dataFeed.sortInPlace({$0.index_Initial > $1.index_Initial})
               if self.dataFeed.count == initialFeedCount+5{
                self.dataFeed.sortInPlace({$0.index_Initial > $1.index_Initial})
                self.customTableView.reloadData()

            }
          }

         }
        }, withCancelBlock: {(err) in

            print(err.localizedDescription)


      })

    }else if totalNoOfPost - initialFeedCount - 4 <= 0{


        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("index").queryStartingAtValue(0).queryEndingAtValue(totalNoOfPost - initialFeedCount).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(recievedSnap) in

            if recievedSnap.exists(){

            for each in recievedSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]{

                let temp = dataS.init(post: each.1["text"] as! String, ind : each.1["index"] as! Int)

                self.dataFeed.insert(temp, atIndex: 5 * Int(self.dataFeed.count/5))
                self.dataFeed.sortInPlace({$0.index_Initial > $1.index_Initial})
                if self.dataFeed.count == initialFeedCount+4{
                   self.dataFeed.sortInPlace({$0.index_Initial > $1.index_Initial})
                    self.customTableView.reloadData()
                        self.pagingSpinner.stopAnimating()
                }
              }
            }else{

            self.pagingSpinner.stopAnimating()
            }

            }, withCancelBlock: {(err) in

                print(err.localizedDescription)


        })
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row + 1) == dataFeed.count {
        print("Displayed the last row!")


                    pagingSpinner.startAnimating()
                    pagingSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
                    pagingSpinner.sizeToFit()
                    customTableView.tableFooterView = pagingSpinner
                    loadMore()
    }
}


}


struct dataS {

var postData : String!
var index_Initial : Int!

init(post : String!, ind : Int!)
{
 self.postData = post
 self.index_Initial = ind
  }

}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123147/discussion-between-dravidian-and-askaale).

Comment: your code sure helped me a lot, but how do you handle the case, when a child gets changed? let's say`postData` from the node gets changed, then the code get recalled because of `observeEventType`. i have tried to use your code in my controller. but it has, for example a child, likes. once a new like gets added, the code from `loadMore` gets triggered again and the posts getting added multiple times. before i have used `myPostArray.removeAll()`, how would i handle it with your approach?

Comment: also. how does the "index" thing handle the case that 1 or 2 posts might get deleted by user? then we would have a gap in indexes? how would that affect the further loads?

Comment: For that effective indexing in your *post* system, you will have to add a separate node in your database consisting of ***active_Indexes*** in which you will append/remove the index no from that node as the respective actions are performed. Now just pick the active 5 index no, search for them and retrieve and update your UI. Now the actual thing will be much more complicated than that but you gotta brain your way through it... this is actually quite a complex situation.. But i have shown you the basic to where to begin from...Manipulate according to your needs

Comment: The basic idea is to keep a separate node that carries active index's from where you can filter and search through

Comment: i was able to find a work around for the child removed issue. the only remaining problem for me is, how to do that with different nodes. like explained, how would i do that for different users within the same feed. like facebook's home feed

Comment: SO is a terrible debugging tool, as i said its a complex query. That would not only depend on how you are retrieving your data and also storing it(JSON datastructure ) but what sorting algorithm you are using to update the feed. I will try'n explain as much as i can from a similar app that i developed - consider a multi user platform, within every usersID node you store its personal info and **posts_To_Show** (the postID's of the posts that you wanna show in your user feed - can be of it's own posts or its friends post)

Comment: now every user will carry a child node namely ***active_Post_Indexes*** (which will contain the index of every post that is in posts_To_Show) whenever a post gets deleted remove its existence from your database wherever it might be present(its details, its ID from postsToShow of every user that might be seeing that post)

Comment: Pick the first five ***active_Post_Indexes*** from that node according to the above algorithm and search them through your ** posts_To_Show** structure -- retrieve them -- update your UI ... i hope that solves it but i kinda have a feeling that it still wont, you gotta brain your way through  ... :)))  Happy Coding @DavidSeek