# Firebase Combining Query and Pagination

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Query** can be used to filter a large items down to a smaller number suitable for synchronizing to the client.
**Pagination** is a also serve the same purpose, that is to limit the items to a smaller numbers suitable to be be fetched by the client.

Consider the following database schema:

```
"users": {
    "-KRyXWjI0X6UvffIB_Gc": {
        "active": true,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "occupation": "Looking for firebase answer"
    },
    "-KRyXBWwaK112OWGw5fa": {
        "active": false,
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "occupation": "Still stuck on combining query and pagination"
    },
    "-KRyWfOg7Nj59qtoCG30": {
        "active": true,
        "name": "Johnnie Doe",
        "occupation": "There is no greater sorrow than to recall in misery the time when we were stuck"
    }
}
```

If I were to get all the active users, it will be like this: (Code in Swift)

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users");
let query = usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("active")
                    .queryEqualToValue(true)
```

After that filtering, it left me with 10,000 users. Fetching all of those users at the same time is out of question. It must be paginated.

To do the pagination, I have to do the query on the unique sorted value, which is none other than the **key** itself. This is how it looks now:

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users");
let query = usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("active")
                    .queryEqualToValue(true)

let usersPerPage = 10;
query.queryOrderedByKey()
     .queryStartingAtValue(lastKey)
     .queryLimitedToFirst(usersPerPage)
```

This wouldn't work because:

> You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by
>   method multiple times in the same query throws an error.

After I spent 2 days on thinking how am I supposed to solve this situation, I can only came up with this "anti best practice" solution.

I modified the database schema. I convert the **active** boolean value to the string and append it after the key to give the order importance control to the key. This is how it looks now:

```
"users": {
    "-KRyXWjI0X6UvffIB_Gc": {
        "key_active": "-KRyXWjI0X6UvffIB_Gc true"
        "active": true,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "occupation": "Looking for firebase answer"
    }
}
```

Now I could do both the pagination and the query using the single orderBy:

```
let usersPerPage = 10;
query.queryOrderedByChild("key_active")
     .queryStartingAtValue("\(lastKey) true")
     .queryLimitedToFirst(usersPerPage)
```

Somehow my brain reject the idea of having the **key** inside the **key** because it's the worst dirty solution it can be. I want to know the right solution for this particular situation, any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to retrieve only 10 users at a time?

Comment: 10 active users at a time. Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your JSON tree:-

```
 active_Users :{
      uid1 : {
             index : 1,
             name : "John Doe"
                },
      uid2 : {
             index : 2,
             name : "Johnnie Doe"
        }
 }
```

After this just follow this answer :-      [Retrieving 5 user's at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430628/retrieve-only-5-users-at-a-time-firebase-like-instagram), modify it according to your requirements.

**Note:-**  Total no of users/posts in that answers is being retrieved by doing children count. Given your heavy database, you might wanna store totalNoOfUser in a separate node and increment it every time a new user is added.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly. It should only return the active users. Besides, incrementing index is not good. The data in the db might have changed by the time the client success incrementing the index because of the client latency is different between clients. That will generate an issue of the newer data become older than old data. It's old SQL approach to save the id. Because we use JSON type DB, it's better if we use the alphabetical key generated from timestamp and some random number (base 64 encoded), And that kind functionality is already supported in Firebase (the key itself).

Comment: You do realise `active_Users ` is  a completely different node, in which you will append or delete a uid whenever that uid toggles between active or inactive mode.

Comment: For the data that can be changed, you can use transactions in Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions