# Download Images from Firebase/Storage with regards to "Last modified"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I want to download Images from my Firebase/Storage with regards to when they were uploaded.
Meaning, that the last uploaded picture will be the first one in my newsfeed (somewhat like instagram).

How could I write such a code?
I don't really know where to start, do I make an ImageArray, or do I have to define every UIImageView?
I can not find help provided by Firebase regarding this topic.

Help is appreciated.
Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39437711/6297658

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I am using Firebase-Storage.
Do I now integrate the Firebase/Database to show the Images ?

Comment: You must be saving those images links somewhere? save the links with the post.. or figure out a workaround,,,:) Happy Coding

Comment: Hello Dravidian,

I am trying to implement your code. Thank you.

I only have a small issue.
"    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}

In this line where i write as! customTableViewCell;
it gives me an error saying: "Use of undeclared identifier 'customTableViewCell'" - Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

We highly recommend using Firebase Storage and the Firebase Realtime Database together to accomplish this. Here's a full example of something similar:

Shared:

```
// Firebase services
var database: FIRDatabase!
var storage: FIRStorage!
...
// Initialize Database, Auth, Storage
database = FIRDatabase.database()
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
...
// Initialize an array for your pictures
var picArray: [UIImage]()
```

Upload:

```
let fileData = NSData() // get data...
let storageRef = storage.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
storageRef.putData(fileData).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
  // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
  let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
  // Write the download URL to the Realtime Database
  let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
  dbRef.setValue(downloadURL)
}
```

Download:

```
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles")
dbRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Get download URL from snapshot
  let downloadURL = snapshot.value() as! String
  // Create a storage reference from the URL
  let storageRef = storage.referenceFromURL(downloadURL)
  // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
  storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
    // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
    let pic = UIImage(data: data)
    picArray.append(pic)
  })
})
```

At this point, you can simply use the images in `picArray` to display them in a `tableView`. You can even use a Firebase Database query to query ordered by a timestamp of the file or other information (you'll want to write that when you write the URL to the database).

For more information, see [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), and it's [associated source code](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd), for a practical example of how to do this.