# Use of undeclared identifier "customTableViewCell"

Tags: swift, xcode, identifier, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to implement a code that was suggest in this discussion; [[Retrieve only 5 users at a time :Firebase [like Instagram]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430628/retrieve-only-5-users-at-a-time-firebase-like-instagram/39437711#39437711])

Unfortunately I am getting the following error, that I can't solve:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = customTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell1","customCell2","customCell3","customCell4","customCell5") as! customTableViewCell
    if dataFeed.count > 0{
        cell.poatLabel.text = dataFeed[indexPath.row].postData
    }
    return cell
}
```

It says "use of undeclared identifier 'customTableViewCell'"..
How do I solve this?
Do I declare the Cells somewhere ?

Help appreciated. Thanks,
Leo

Comment: Where is `customTableViewCell` class defined?

Comment: Nowhere I guess. How would I define it?
""let customTableViewCell = cell'''' ?

Comment: And i think you cant take more than one cell in `deque`, Never done that. You have not defined `Class CustomTableViewCell:UITableViewCell ` anywhere?

Comment: Isn't the error actually *Cannot invoke 'dequeueReusableCell' with an argument list of type '(withIdentifier: String, String, String, String, String, for:indexPath)* ? ;-)

Comment: @Mr.UB

I have it like this:
        class Something: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

_____
Sorry I am new to coding

Comment: @vadian No, the error is as I said; "Use of undeclared.." Thanks

Comment: Create a new file with `UITableViewCell` and assign that class to the Prototype cell in the IBInspector.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I have not done that yet, that might help.

Comment: Aaaaand it didn't :(

I tried UITableViewCell, UITableViewController, none of it worked.

Comment: @leo,  if you cast a cell to a specific type this type (class) must exist and the class of the cell must be set to that custom class. Regarding my first comment:  you will get the mentioned error after having resolved yours ;-)

Comment: @vadian Thank you, I created a new file (class).
But what do I do now? What do I use the class for ?
do I have to declare the Images(data) that will be shown in the Cells within that class?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Storyboard. Select the table view cell. Check the identifier.

Comment: I called it customTableViewCell. It didn't work.
Also i have 5 Cells, that all need to be named differently.

Comment: Do the cells physically on storyboard? Then take 5 cells and set their indentifier name their separetlly

Comment: I did that, I named them customTableViewCell1.2.3.4 & 5, but it is still the same error..

Comment: But in your code you write 'customCell1' and others. make a variable string where the value will be customTableViewCell.and add 1, 2,3 dynamically checking the cell indexpath

Answer (score 0):

as you said it worked for me to create a new class.
A "TableViewCell" class. So far it works.

I do not have a class that is called TableViewController thought.
Might run into errors further down the road...

Thank you