# How can i get the auto generated key of Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase structure]

I have the Firebase structure like that. So how can i get and print out the string of auto generate key and its index?

Its my code but still print out `10093`

```
databaseReference.child("Message").child(senderId).child(receiverId!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            self.databaseReference.child("Message").child(self.senderId).child(self.receiverId!).child(snapshot.key).observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
                print("aaa \(snap.key)")
    })
})
```

What i'm missing or something wrong? Please fix it for me. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
databaseReference.child("Message").child(senderId).child(receiverId!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
       for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print(users.key)
       }
    }
})
```

A `DataSnapshot` contains data from a Database location. It has key and value properties.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you :)

Comment: do you know how to use query to load 5 more children once time? I detect the last child in first 5 children already but do not know how to get the next 5 children from the last. My code is right below

Comment: databaseReference.child("Message").child(senderId).child(receiverId!).queryStarting(atValue: keyFirebase[0]).queryLimited(toFirst: 5).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
             
            })

Comment: Do you want last 5 children?

Comment: i want to make load more function. The first one load 5 messages. Then when user pull to load more, i want to load more from the last messages of the first 5 message in the first load

Comment: refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430628/retrieve-only-5-users-at-a-time-firebase-like-instagram

Answer (score 1):

When you observe any reference in firebase, you get a `DataSnapshot` in return. The **snapshot** has a `children` enumerator property on which you can enumerate each child. Each of the child will be another `DataSnapshot`. Now, each **snapshot** has `key` and `value`. You want the `key`? Just use the `key` property:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Message").child("1577").child("10093")
databaseRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    snapshot.children.forEach({ (child) in
        if let child = child as? DataSnapshot {
            let key = child.key
            print(key)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Message").child("1577").child("10093")
 databaseRef.observe(.childAdded)
    { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in           
        print(snapshot.key)
    }
```