# Swift - Value not updating after completion handler

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

I am new to Swift programming and trying to return a value for my tableView numberOfSections. I am also new to completion handlers. If I go into debug mode and run my code line by line, count does get "updated" in numberOfSections. However when it gets to the return statement, count remains at a value of 0.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var count = 0
    let firebase = ref.child("Menu").child("Category").child("Cookies")
    getCount(ref: firebase) { (myCount) in
        print("Complete")
        count = myCount
    }
    return count
}

func getCount(ref:DatabaseReference, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()){
    var count = 0
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        completion(count)
    }
}
```

Comment: `return count` is not **after** completion handler. Your `getCount(ref:completion:)` returns immediately before your completion handler is executed. So, `return count` is executed while `count` is still `0`. And after some amount of time when the async operation is completed, your completion handler `{ (myCount) in ... }` is executed. Generally, you cannot use async methods inside `numberOfSections(in:)`. Load your data model somewhere else and call `tableView.reloadData()` when loading completed. Sh_Khan's answer is well outlining what you need to do.

Comment: You're not going to want to do this - it's going to be laggy and not provide a good experience for the user. Best practice is to load the data you want displayed in your tableview into a datasource, then populate the tableview. Count would come from that datasource so it will diminish pinging Firebase. TableViews, collectionViews etc should be backed by an in-memory [datasource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1531866-datasource). Then check out [Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430628/retrieve-only-5-users-at-a-time-firebase-like-instagram)

Answer (score 0):

The process is asynchronous , you need

```
var count = 0 // instance var

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() // you missed this =D
    let firebase = ref.child("Menu").child("Category").child("Cookies")
    getCount(ref: firebase) { (myCount) in
        print("Complete")
        count = myCount
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return count
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple reasons why the count variable isn't updating in the numberOfSections function.

1. Count is an Int, which makes it a value type, which means a copy is made in the closure so the count inside the closure is different from the one outside the closure.
2. The fetch from the data base is asynchronous, meaning count will be returned and go out of scope before the closure has been executed.

Try this to see if it works.

```
    // this variable now lives beyond the scope of the function
    var sectionCount: Int = 0 

    // fetch every time you come into this screen, 
    // so pushing and popping new screens on top of this one
    // will update it
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        // make your async call to your db
        let firebase = ref.child("Menu").child("Category").child("Cookies")

        // remember to weak reference 'self' to avoid retain cycles
        getCount(ref: firebase) { [weak self] (myCount) in
            // update the section count
            self?.sectionCount = myCount
            // tell the table view to update itself, this will tell it 
            // to call numberOfSections, cellForIndex, and other functions 
            // to update the table view 
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sectionCount
    }
```