# How to keep track of processed users?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have this dict:

```
var userDict : [String : Bool] = ["": true]
```

Which I want to use so I can quickly and efficiently check if a user has already been processed. The issue is that I am unable to add values to it. I have done the below as seen in popular answers found online. How can I fix this?

```
var processedUsers = Set<String>()
func search() {
for u in snapChildren {
            print(u, " this is one of the users")

                let uid = self.getUID(snapshot: u)

                print(" Is \(uid) in processedUsers?", processedUsers.contains(uid), " This is the entiere thing: ", processedUsers)
                if !processedUsers.contains(uid) {
                    print("hfsghfdsagfkdsafjlksadfhjklasdfhlksahfjklsadfhakd")
                    let user = User(theuserID: uid)
                    self.retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: user, completion: {
                        self.peopleArray.append(user)
                        self.processedUsers.insert(user.userID!)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
```

To be clear. I want to add values such as `["HDSFG2323BFYDSG54": true]`

### update:

I have included more code for context. I have a loop which loops over users. Inside I need to determine if the user has already been processed.

From print statements I have found that for many loops despite having gotten that the uid is not in the container, it does not seem to add it as in the next loop the container is empty.

Comment: Strictly spoken you cannot *append* values to a dictionary. Nevertheless your code looks correct. If the value for the `uid` key doesn't exist  set the key/value pair.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am unable to add values to it`? What happens when you try to do that?

Comment: @Cristik key value pairs,

Comment: Your latest update makes it appear even more confusing. If you're adding completed users to `processedUsers`, it should work. See my updated example. If it's still not working, use breakpoints to debug `retrieveUsersInfo` — you're likely expecting events to happen out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only goal you are trying to achieve is to keep track of users that have already been processed, you can use **Set** instead

```
var processedUsers = Set<String>()
...
processedUsers.insert(freshlyProcessedUsersUid) // insert
processedUsers.contains(uid) //checking if already has been processed
```

So your code may be something like:

```
if !processedUsers.contains(uid) {
    let user = User(theuserID: uid)
    self.retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: user, completion: {
        self.peopleArray.append(user)
        self.processedUsers.insert(user.uid)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Agreed, `Set` is a much more suitable tool for solving this problem.

Comment: there is no chance for a `Set` to have duplicated values

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more/less correct. Here's a simplification of it that runs inside a playground where you can see that your logic works. As @vadian points out, you're not "appending" to a dict, instead you are assigning a value to a property, but as vdmzz points out, you should and could do this with a `Set`.

```
import UIKit

struct User {
    var uid: String
}

var processedUsers: Set<String> = Set()

var uids = ["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59", "ODSFG2323BABDSG50"]

uids.forEach({
    if !processedUsers.contains($0) {
        let user = User(uid: $0)
        processedUsers.insert(user.uid)
        print(processedUsers)
    }
})
```

Prints:

```
["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53"]
["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59"]
["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "ODSFG2323BABDSG50", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59"]
```

But, I highly suspect the reason your code still isn't working is because of the asynchronous nature of `retrieveUsersInfo`. You're looping through the entire `Set` in its empty state, and populating it with the value of the user *after* it is retrieved. Here's a demonstration of what I think is happening:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct User {
    var uid: String
}

func retrieveUsersInfo(uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        let user = User(uid: uid)
        completion(user)
    }
}

var processedUsers: Set<String> = Set()

var uids = ["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59", "ODSFG2323BABDSG50"]

uids.forEach({
    if !processedUsers.contains($0) {
        retrieveUsersInfo(uid: $0, completion: { (user) in
            processedUsers.insert(user.uid)
            print("Callback returned", processedUsers)
        })
        print("Loop ended", processedUsers)
    }
})

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Output:

```
Loop ended []
Loop ended []
Loop ended []
Callback returned ["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53"]
Callback returned ["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59"]
Callback returned ["HDSFG2323BGYDSG53", "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59", "ODSFG2323BABDSG50"]
```

So, your Set will always be empty at the end of the loop because the async task hasn't returned. This might be OK if you're keeping a persistent record (NSUserDefaults, CoreData) of the uids you've processed, but if this is ephemeral — meaning it will disappear when the app closes, you'll want to beef up your processing log with something like "state" (but there a dozen different ways you could solve it that aren't this).

Here's an example that implements `Hashable` state:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct User {
    var uid: String
    var state: ProcessedState

    init(uid: String) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.state = .none
    }

    enum ProcessedState {
        case none
        case started
        case success
        case error
    }
}

extension User: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
}

extension User: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return uid.hashValue
    }
}

func retrieveUsersInfo(user: User, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        var user = user
        user.state = .success // or .error
        completion(user)
    }
}

var processedUsers: Set<User> = Set()

var users: [User] = [
    User(uid: "HDSFG2323BGYDSG53"),
    User(uid: "JDSFG2323BPTDSG59"),
    User(uid: "ODSFG2323BABDSG50")]

users.forEach({ user in
    if processedUsers.first(where: { $0 == user })?.state != .success {
        var user = user
        user.state = .started
        processedUsers.insert(user)
        retrieveUsersInfo(user: user, completion: { (user) in
            print("Callback returned", processedUsers)
        })
        print("Loop ended", processedUsers)
    }
})

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: You are correct and was only able to fix this by fixing my willdisplay code, you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430628/retrieve-only-5-users-at-a-time-firebase-like-instagram. I am marking the other answer though as that is the one I chose to go with.

Comment: Sure thing, good luck. I added an example for using `Hashable` to support a state property just in case it's useful to you.